# SQL to return unique combinations of non key columns within a set of key columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In SQL Server, I have a target table STAGNG_PA_BK_FEED_REVNU_SUM, that has the following 7 columns that make up its unique index. I want to populate this table using data primarily from the STAGNG_PA_BK_FEED_REVNU_DTL table. The data in the target table includes an amount field, REVNU_AMT, that is aggregated by grouping on all of the other selected/non aggregated columns.

Because we are selecting addition "property" columns that are not included in the unique key of the target table, the insert will fail if we get more than one distinct combination of values for the property columns within a key grouping. When this happens, I want to be able to identify the all of the source records that share the same primary key but have different property value combinations. In other words, I want to be able to produce a report of the complete source records so that the business users can identify the offending records that cause the unique key violation when inserting.

```
INSERT INTO dbo.STAGNG_PA_BK_FEED_REVNU_SUM
    (
    --Keys of target table
    RBT_YR_DT
  , MLR_SRC_SYS_CD
  , LGL_ENTTY_CD
  , CLIENT_ID
  , CLIENT_ACCT_NUM
  , BEN_PLAN_ID
  , CLIENT_CNTRCT_ST_CD

    --Properties of target table
  , MLR_EXTRT_SYS_CD
  , PA_LGL_ENTTY_CD
  , COA_CO_CD
  , COMMRCL_BUS_IND
  , COA_SITUS_ST_CD
  , ASGND_SITUS_STE_IND
  , CLIENT_TY_CD
  , MLR_SEG_CD
  
  --Fact
  
  , REVNU_AMT
    
    )
SELECT
    --values for keys of target table
    D.RBT_YR_DT
  , D.MLR_SRC_SYS_CD
  , D.LGL_ENTTY_CD
  , D.CLIENT_ID
  , D.CLIENT_ACCT_NUM
  , D.BEN_PLAN_ID
  , J.SITUS_STE_CD   AS CLIENT_CNTRCT_ST_CD

    --values for properties of target table
  , D.MLR_EXTRT_SYS_CD
  , D.PA_LGL_ENTTY_CD
  , D.COA_CO_CD
  , D.COMMRCL_BUS_IND
  , D.COA_SITUS_ST_CD
  , 'N'              AS ASGND_SITUS_STE_IND   
  , D.CLIENT_TY_CD
  , D.MLR_SEG_CD

  --Fact
  ,SUM(D.REVNU_AMT) AS REVNU_AMT
  
FROM
    dbo.STAGNG_PA_BK_FEED_REVNU_DTL D
        INNER JOIN JE_NT_STE_MAP J
            ON D.COA_SITUS_ST_CD = J.CONTRACT_SITUS_STATE
GROUP BY
    --PK
    D.RBT_YR_DT
  , D.MLR_SRC_SYS_CD
  , D.LGL_ENTTY_CD
  , D.CLIENT_ID
  , D.CLIENT_ACCT_NUM
  , D.BEN_PLAN_ID
  , J.SITUS_STE_CD

    --Properties
    -- Must be unique distinct group of value within the key grouping else key violation on target will result
  , D.MLR_EXTRT_SYS_CD
  , D.PA_LGL_ENTTY_CD
  , D.COA_CO_CD
  , D.COMMRCL_BUS_IND
  , D.COA_SITUS_ST_CD
  , D.CLIENT_TY_CD
  , D.MLR_SEG_CD
```

### Update

I previously considered using Jaime's approach of concatenating all of the property values into a single value so the DISTINCT verb could be applied in the HAVING clause.

Taking his answer, I modified it to display a report all of the records in the source table that need to be examined  and corrected in order to prevent the duplicate key violation, which was my goal, not just display the duplicated non key values.

```
WITH DUPS AS
(
    SELECT
        --values for keys of target table
        D.RBT_YR_DT
      , D.MLR_SRC_SYS_CD
      , D.LGL_ENTTY_CD
      , D.CLIENT_ID
      , D.CLIENT_ACCT_NUM
      , D.BEN_PLAN_ID
      , J.SITUS_STE_CD              AS CLIENT_CNTRCT_ST_CD
    FROM
        dbo.STAGNG_PA_BK_FEED_REVNU_DTL D
            INNER JOIN JE_NT_STE_MAP J
                ON D.COA_SITUS_ST_CD = J.CONTRACT_SITUS_STATE
    GROUP BY
        --PK
        D.RBT_YR_DT
      , D.MLR_SRC_SYS_CD
      , D.LGL_ENTTY_CD
      , D.CLIENT_ID
      , D.CLIENT_ACCT_NUM
      , D.BEN_PLAN_ID
      , J.SITUS_STE_CD
    HAVING
        COUNT(DISTINCT
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), D.MLR_EXTRT_SYS_CD) + '-' +
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), D.PA_LGL_ENTTY_CD) + '-' +
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), D.COA_CO_CD) + '-' +
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), D.COMMRCL_BUS_IND) + '-' +
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), D.COA_SITUS_ST_CD) + '-' +
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), D.CLIENT_TY_CD) + '-' +
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), D.MLR_SEG_CD)
        ) > 1
)
SELECT
        --Keys
        D.RBT_YR_DT
      , D.MLR_SRC_SYS_CD
      , D.LGL_ENTTY_CD
      , D.CLIENT_ID
      , D.CLIENT_ACCT_NUM
      , D.BEN_PLAN_ID
      , D.COA_SITUS_ST_CD

      --Properties that have dups with a key groups
      , D.MLR_EXTRT_SYS_CD
      , D.PA_LGL_ENTTY_CD
      , D.COA_CO_CD
      , D.COMMRCL_BUS_IND
      , D.COA_SITUS_ST_CD
--      , 'N'              AS ASGND_SITUS_STE_IND   
      , D.CLIENT_TY_CD
      , D.MLR_SEG_CD

FROM
    STAGNG_PA_BK_FEED_REVNU_DTL D
        INNER JOIN JE_NT_STE_MAP J
                ON D.COA_SITUS_ST_CD = J.CONTRACT_SITUS_STATE
    inner join DUPS ON 

        DUPS.RBT_YR_DT           = D.RBT_YR_DT
    AND DUPS.MLR_SRC_SYS_CD      = D.MLR_SRC_SYS_CD
    AND DUPS.LGL_ENTTY_CD        = D.LGL_ENTTY_CD
    AND DUPS.CLIENT_ID           = D.CLIENT_ID
    AND DUPS.CLIENT_ACCT_NUM     = D.CLIENT_ACCT_NUM
    AND DUPS.BEN_PLAN_ID         = D.BEN_PLAN_ID
    AND DUPS.CLIENT_CNTRCT_ST_CD = J.SITUS_STE_CD

order by 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14
```

While this may work in practice I find it a little kludgy and in the end I may be displaying records that had a duplicate non-key that appeared *another* key grouping but only appeared there once, so the end report may not be accurate.

Comment: Can you add some data to test the answer? @Chad

Comment: @Chad, shouldn't it better if you delete this question, since https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67939946/write-sql-to-identify-multiple-subgroupings-within-a-grouping/67940339#67940339 is a better statement?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this could help you to find those PK with more than 1 different properties combination

```
SELECT
   --values for keys of target table
   D.RBT_YR_DT
  ,D.MLR_SRC_SYS_CD
  ,D.LGL_ENTTY_CD
  ,D.CLIENT_ID
  ,D.CLIENT_ACCT_NUM
  ,D.BEN_PLAN_ID
  ,J.SITUS_STE_CD   AS CLIENT_CNTRCT_ST_CD
FROM dbo.STAGNG_PA_BK_FEED_REVNU_DTL D
  INNER JOIN JE_NT_STE_MAP J
    ON D.COA_SITUS_ST_CD = J.CONTRACT_SITUS_STATE
GROUP BY
   --PK
   D.RBT_YR_DT
  ,D.MLR_SRC_SYS_CD
  ,D.LGL_ENTTY_CD
  ,D.CLIENT_ID
  ,D.CLIENT_ACCT_NUM
  ,D.BEN_PLAN_ID
  ,J.SITUS_STE_CD
HAVING
    COUNT(DISTINCT
      CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),D.MLR_EXTRT_SYS_CD) + '-' +
      CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),D.PA_LGL_ENTTY_CD) + '-' +
      CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),D.COA_CO_CD) + '-' +
      CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),D.COMMRCL_BUS_IND) + '-' +
      CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),D.COA_SITUS_ST_CD) + '-' +
      CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),'N' AS ASGND_SITUS_STE_IND) + '-' +
      CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),D.CLIENT_TY_CD) + '-' +
      CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),D.MLR_SEG_CD)
    ) > 1
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer which I up voted as useful but I feel like it is not ideal. In my updated question comments, I mentioned my concerns for my end goal of producing a report which showed a grouping of all records that shared the same key but had varying grouping of non key columns. Even if the final outcome was perfect, I feel like there has to be a better way that concatenating non keys columns in a single field to be able to apply the DISTINCT word. I do appreciate your input and I hope your not discouraged by my reservations.

Comment: I was wondering whether a PARTITION window clause could be applied to identify multiple non keys groupings within a key group...

Comment: Hi @Chad, no problem at all... partition window functions cannot be used together with group by. In addition, if you want to get this report using partition functions, it will be even more convoluted that this one, because, for example, using row_number, you would need to partition by all your fields (keys + properties), identifying those keys with a row_number > 2 as interesting.

Comment: I know that, in a first sight, the solution doesn't seem very attractive, but dealing with so many fields I can't think of a way cleaner

Answer (score 0):

Just use window functions:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT D.*, J.*,   -- may need to select particular columns to avoid duplicate column names
            COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY D.RBT_YR_DT, D.MLR_SRC_SYS_CD, D.LGL_ENTTY_CD,
                                        D.CLIENT_ID, D.CLIENT_ACCT_NUM, D.BEN_PLAN_ID, J.SITUS_STE_CD,
                                        D.MLR_EXTRT_SYS_CD, D.PA_LGL_ENTTY_CD, D.COA_CO_CD, 
                                        D.COMMRCL_BUS_IND, D.COA_SITUS_ST_CD, D.CLIENT_TY_C
                          ) as cnt
      FROM dbo.STAGNG_PA_BK_FEED_REVNU_DTL D INNER JOIN
           JE_NT_STE_MAP J
           ON D.COA_SITUS_ST_CD = J.CONTRACT_SITUS_STATE
     ) DJ
WHERE cnt >= 2;
```