# Write SQL to identify multiple subgroupings within a grouping

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a program that summarizes non-normalized data in one table and moves it to another and we frequently get a duplicate key violation on the insert due to bad data. I want to create a report for the users to help them identify the cause of the error.

For example, consider the following contrived simple SQL which summarizes data in the table Companies and inserts it into CompanySum, which has a primary key of State/Zone. In order for the INSERT not to fail, there cannot be more than one distinct combinations of Company/Code for every unique primary key State/Zone combination. If there is, we want the insert to fail so that the data can be corrected.

```
INSERT INTO CompanySum
(
    [State] 
    ,[Zone] 
    ,[Company]
    ,[Code] 
    ,[Revenue] 
)
SELECT 
    --Keys of target
    [State] 
    ,[Zone] 

    --We are expecting to have one distinct combination of these fields per key grouping
    ,[Company]
    ,[Code] 

    --Aggregate
    ,SUM([Revenue])
    
FROM COMPANIES

GROUP BY
    [State] 
    ,[Zone] 
    ,[Company]
    ,[Code]
```

I would like to create a report to help the users easily identify and correct the data so that there is only one distinct Company/Code combination within a State/Zone.  For each distinct State/Zone value, I would like to identify the distinct Company/Code combinations within the State/Zone. If there are more than one Company/Code combinations within a State/Zone, I would like all of the records in the State/Zone to be displayed in the output. For example, here is the sample input and desired output:

```
Data:

RecordNumber    State   Zone    Company         Code    Revenue
------------    -----   ----    -------         ----    --------
1               CT      B       State of CT     65453    10
2               CT      B       State of CT     65453     3
3               CT      B       Travelers       33443    20
4               CT      C       Cigna           45678    24
5               CT      C       Cigna           45678   234
6               MI      A       GM              48089   100
7               MI      A       GM              54555   200
8               MI      B       Chrysler        43434    44


Desired Output:

RecordNumber    State   Zone    Company         Code    Revenue
------------    -----   ----    -------         ----    --------
1               CT      B       State of CT     65453     10
2               CT      B       State of CT     65453      3
3               CT      B       Travelers       33443     20
6               MI      A       GM              48089    100
7               MI      A       GM              54555    200
```

Here is the DDL and DML needed to create this test scenario

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Companies](
    [RecordNumber] [int] NULL,
    [State] [char](2) NOT NULL,
    [Zone] [varchar](30) NOT NULL,
    [Company] [varchar](30) NOT NULL,
    [Code] [varchar](30) NOT NULL,
    [Revenue] [numeric](9, 1) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CompanySum](
    [State] [char](2) NOT NULL,
    [Zone] [varchar](30) NOT NULL,
    [Company] [varchar](30) NOT NULL,
    [Code] [varchar](30) NOT NULL,
    [Revenue] [numeric](9, 1) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_CompanySum] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [State] ASC,
    [Zone] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]


DELETE FROM [dbo].[Companies]
GO

INSERT [dbo].[Companies] ([RecordNumber], [State], [Zone], [Company], [Code], [Revenue]) VALUES (1, N'CT', N'B', N'State of CT', N'65453', CAST(10.0 AS Numeric(9, 1)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Companies] ([RecordNumber], [State], [Zone], [Company], [Code], [Revenue]) VALUES (2, N'CT', N'B', N'State of CT', N'65453', CAST(3.0 AS Numeric(9, 1)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Companies] ([RecordNumber], [State], [Zone], [Company], [Code], [Revenue]) VALUES (3, N'CT', N'B', N'Travelers', N'33443', CAST(20.0 AS Numeric(9, 1)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Companies] ([RecordNumber], [State], [Zone], [Company], [Code], [Revenue]) VALUES (4, N'CT', N'C', N'Cigna', N'45678', CAST(24.0 AS Numeric(9, 1)))
INSERT [dbo].[Companies] ([RecordNumber], [State], [Zone], [Company], [Code], [Revenue]) VALUES (5, N'CT', N'C', N'Cigna', N'45678', CAST(234.0 AS Numeric(9, 1)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Companies] ([RecordNumber], [State], [Zone], [Company], [Code], [Revenue]) VALUES (6, N'MI', N'A', N'GM', N'48089', CAST(100.0 AS Numeric(9, 1)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Companies] ([RecordNumber], [State], [Zone], [Company], [Code], [Revenue]) VALUES (7, N'MI', N'A', N'GM', N'54555', CAST(200.0 AS Numeric(9, 1)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Companies] ([RecordNumber], [State], [Zone], [Company], [Code], [Revenue]) VALUES (8, N'MI', N'B', N'Chrysler', N'43434', CAST(44.0 AS Numeric(9, 1)))
GO
```

This is a hopefully better re-construction of a previous post of mine [SQL to return unique combinations of non key columns within a set of key columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67928531/sql-to-return-unique-combinations-of-non-key-columns-within-a-set-of-key-columns/67929998#67929998) where I am trying to help clarify the question and provide a simple working example  that readers can use.

Please see this SQL Fiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d0141/1

Comment: I do not see any duplicate in the sample data.

Comment: State Zone Company Code (No column name)
CT B State of CT 65453 13.0
CT B Travelers 33443 20.0
CT C Cigna 45678 258.0
MI A GM 48089 100.0
MI A GM 54555 200.0
MI B Chrysler 43434 44.0

Comment: Also: Why do you exclude Chrysler in your desired output Why you don't SUM State of CT in your desired output.

Comment: Thank you for your input.  I excluded Chrysler from the output because there was only one distinct Company/Code combination within the State zone. I did not SUM(REVENUE) because I am trying to create a report to show the original data in the source rows that should be reviewed in order to avoid the dup key issue. When I insert into the SUM table, I will SUM(REVENUE) but the report I would like to create just shows the original row data for all the rows that have multiple Company/Code combinations within a State/Zone.

Comment: OK, based on the same logic, why do you exclude Cigna?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this a solution?

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/12e9a0/9

```
select c.*
from
    Companies c
        inner join (
            select State, Zone
            from Companies
            group by State, Zone
            having count(distinct Company + Code) > 1
        ) as dup_state_zone
        on(
                c.State = dup_state_zone.State
            and c.Zone  = dup_state_zone.Zone
        )
```

**Edited** - Fix the having clause, with a little cheat...

Comment: @Marus. Thanks, Marcus, but the output includes records 4 nd 5 for the CT/C  State/Zone even though there is only one distinct Company/Code, Cigna/45678, within it.

Comment: @Chad, your example data shows 2 records with Cigna/45678 in CT/C (in the table as well as in the INSERTs).

Comment: @Chad, you are right. I rewrote the `dup_state_zone` sub query, cheating a little bit

Comment: yes, the input data in the Companies table does show two rows with a Company/Code combo of Cigna/45678.  This is not a mistake. The source data can be this way. These 2 records belong to a State/Zone of CT/C, and this State/Zone only has the one distinct Company/Code "Cigna/45678" in it, so these two rows will not cause a dup key error when inserting and should not be on the report.

Comment: @Chad, please, check the new version. It's also in this fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/12e9a0/9

Comment: @Chad, by the way, kudos for your pristine question :-)

Comment: Okay, finally I understand your requirement. Then @MarcusViniciusPompeu has the right solution.

Comment: Thanks, @olivier. Stackoverflow needs this kind of chivalry. To be honest, I was running after you :-)

Comment: @marcus. I think you might have gotten it. You used a similar approach to my original posting which I referenced in  my question, namely, concatenating Company/Code values into one so you can use DISTINCT on it.  At first, i thought there was still an issue but that I needed different sample data to show why, but now I am convinced it is also perfect. As stated in the my referenced post, the concating feels a little kludgey and should probably include separators that could not occur in the data between the fields (eg, count(distinct Company + '~mySeprator~' + Code) > 1. (cont in next reply)...

Comment: Because of the need for a separator that is not in the data, I feel like this concating approach is not perfect but still very practical. I wish that DISTINCT verb would allow multiple columns separated by commas or that there was a better way.

Comment: @Chad, I read your previous comments. Well... I also do no like these makeshift solutions :-) I'll try to solve this using windowing functions.

Comment: @Chad, I give up. Do the strings concatenations and be happy :-)

Comment: @Chad Can you please have a look, I posted an answer and I found an error in your insert statement. :)

Comment: What was the error in the insert statement?

Comment: @Chad, I agree with @Gudwlk: he noticed that `CompanySum` has a PK based on `State, Zone` and, since the cases have by statement duplicates on `State, Zone`, any inserts into this table will fail.

Comment: I agree that dups will fail. The intent of the SQL you wrote was to write another SQL that will identify the group of records that share the same Primary Key so that the data owners can correct so data so that the insert doesn't fail . There is nothing wrong with  the key, the data is bad.

Answer (score 1):

I used windows ranking function to rank the records by state ordering by zone ascending, to get the desired output.

Suggestion: I would like to say that the insert statement of your CompanySum will ail due to your primary key constraint as you select duplicate key records.  in this case you need to change your primary key constraint a little.

```
 CONSTRAINT [PK_CompanySum] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
 (
[State] ASC,
[Zone] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
 ) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Since State and zone both are with duplicate values this insert will fail. better add a auto increment primary key, or include RecordNumber in to Primary key constraint rather than using State and Zone to make it usnique as there are duplicate values in your desired output.

```
 SELECT 
  A.[RecordNumber]
 ,A.[State]
 ,A.[Zone]
 ,A.[Company]
 ,A.Code
 ,A.Revenue

FROM 
 (
  SELECT * 
  ,RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY [STATE] ORDER BY Zone) AS [row]
  FROM Companies
 ) AS A
WHERE [row] =1
```

Highlighted are duplicates which will make your insert fail.

[image: Result]

Comment: @Chad Can you check this and let me know any support is required. Marcus Vinicius Pompeu please have a look in to this as well.

Comment: Based on the output, it looks correct but I'll be darned if I understand it. For example, for the inner query 'table A', I expected RecordNumbers 4 and 5 to have a "row" of 2 but instead it had a row of 4. I thought the ranking would be sequential for each distinct Zone within a State. 

I'm confused by your comment about changing the PK. As I see it, the PK is a given and we just want to create a report to help identify where the bad data lies that causes the insert to potentially fail.

Comment: @Chad your primary key is a combination of [State] , [Zone] and the output of the query is with duplicates for the combination of State and Zone. That is where you will fail the insert statement.  That is something apart from the solution and I just wanted to let you know. If you need any help, let me know.

Comment: @Gudwlk, I'm sorry, but the results are OK for sheer luck. I just reverted the `Zone` orders (turning `A` into `C` and vice-versa for `CT`,  and `A` into `B` and vice-versa for `MI`) for illustration: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/611a3/1

Comment: By the way, @Gudwlk, you are right. Insertions in `CompanySum` will fail due the `PK` :-)

Comment: @MarcusViniciusPompeu I normally use windows functions for these kind of stuff as it will be  more generic approach to sort them. since we use a partition by  a column or column list.  Anyways, there are lots of ways to achieve this. As I saw your newer has been accepted, and I saw your last comment of using windows function,  I added this. :)

Comment: @Gudwlk, man, I really tried to find a window functions solution but gave up. If you happen to solve http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/611a3/1 using window functions, please, let us know! This is a very joyful part of SQL language :-)